# Should I change to VeraCrypt on win7 SSD from TrueCrypt 7.1a?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, truecrypt, veracrypt

Is still safe for me to use TrueCrypt or should I change to VeraCrypt as the last update boot won`t take long anymore.
Any backdoors to decrypt TrueCrypt?

Answer (score 1):

**NO**. It is **NOT** safe to use Truecrypt, which was last updated 4 years ago.

[Two CVE's exist](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-17056/Truecrypt.html) but there could be more because Truecrupt is no longer in the interest of security researchers anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to use VeraCrypt. TrueCrypt is not safe any more and they implemented Vera Crypt with support for enhancing the security.

You should be aware that security normally has it's issue such as slower algorithm.But the main security purpose is to make information feasible in a secure way and to prevent any leaks. So then again TrueCrypt has vulnerabilities. Your choice...

Answer (score 0):

Your choice should take in to account what you are trying to protect and why.

If your looking at just personal use then VeraCrypt will be your best choice as already mentioned.

If your looking at encryption to meet some regulatory requirements then you will probably need to purchase a full system.

Another option would be to upgrade to Windows 10 and use Bitlocker.  Again this will depend on your specific environment and requirements for why your still using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use VeraCrypt on a TrueCrypt-encrypted drive! This allows you to avoid migrating to a new encryption scheme, while still being able to use the less vulnerable VeraCrypt program.

The answer depends on what you are trying to be safe *from*. In terms of the security of the encryption itself, both TrueCrypt and VeraCrypt are quite secure. In fact, they use almost identical encryption, though VeraCrypt does use more secure defaults (it uses stronger settings for an algorithm called PBKDF2, which is designed to make brute force attacks slower). There are also no backdoors in TrueCrypt that would allow anyone to decrypt your data without knowing your encryption password.

However, these are programs that have to run constantly on your computer. TrueCrypt has several known bugs that allows an unprivileged compromised user to attack the running TrueCrypt program in order to gain administrative access. This is the most important reason to switch to VeraCrypt.